# Various Win10 issues: network, permissions, crashes, services

Tags: windows-10, dhcp, services

I run a clean Win10 as a VirtualBox guest in a Linux Host. I use it only for very specific tasks (no browsing) and there's very little software installed on it. Lately it's been behaving very strange.

- the network stopped working. The VB NAT won't connect. `ipconfig` returns a 169.254.168.200 address
- it's originally a french version but now half the functionalities are in english (I would prefer if it was all in english)
- for a few days most programs would crash after a few seconds of use, then after a few reboots things came back to normal
- I doubt there are viruses as I only connect(ed) to the net to update apps or the OS.
- many services aren't running, for instance the dhcp client (which explains the lack of network), and trying to get them started runs into all kind of issues. For instance [this](https://www.wintips.org/how-to-fix-dhcp-service-cannot-start-access-is-denied/) tutorial:

  - There is no `nt service\dhcp` name to add
  - `NET LOCALGROUP administrators "NT Authority\Local Service" /add` returns `System error 1376 has occurred The specified local group does not exist`

What can I do to clean/fix things up ? I don't think it's a problem with VirtualBox, it seems to be purely local to Win10.

Comment: `169.254.168.200` is an indication the VM isn't getting an IP address assigned to it by your DHCP server. Can you be more specific about "issues" by editing your question?

Comment: Well, yes, I tried to by mentionning the DHCP service not starting because of missing permissions.